# Netty 4.0 SPDY file transfer not working

Tags: file, http, netty, spdy

For a long time I always run into the same trouble when i try to use SPDY with netty.

I checked different SPDY sources to setup my SPDY server. So far it works fine and I have got a pure html output in my browser. Chrome also shows an spdy session.

**Issue**

When i put the netty 4 `HttpStaticFileServerHandler` example class to the `SPDYorHTTPHandler` I always run into the same problem.

HTML content is sent, but the file content isn't. The handler is sending the response so my client retrieves, but then the files are never transmitted.

Any ideas about that?

`ctx.write(response)` is writing the response to the client (response is a `HttpResponse` obj).

In the next line:(`raf=RandomAccessFile`)

```
ChannelFuture sendFileFuture;
    if (useSendFile) {
        sendFileFuture = ctx.write(new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, fileLength), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
    } else {
        sendFileFuture = ctx.write(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
    }
```

But it never gets written. The code based 100% on the `HttpStaticFileServerHandler` example and the SPDY example of netty 4.

I just changed the `createHttpRequestHandlerForHttp output` from `SpdyServerHandler` to `HttpStaticFileServerHandler`.

This is the pileline I use:

```
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ctx.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("spdyFrameCodec", new SpdyFrameCodec(version));
    pipeline.addLast("spdySessionHandler", new SpdySessionHandler(version,true));
    pipeline.addLast("spdyHttpEncoder", new SpdyHttpEncoder(version));
    pipeline.addLast("spdyHttpDecoder", new SpdyHttpDecoder(version, MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH));
    pipeline.addLast("spdyStreamIdHandler", new SpdyHttpResponseStreamIdHandler());
    pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
    pipeline.addLast("httpRequestHandler",new HttpStaticFileServerHandler());
```

If you need more code for that, just write, I will extend the Post.

I got no errors, warnings or something else.

A `ChannelProgressiveFutureListener` did never call `operationProgressed` function.

Thx dodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
sendFileFuture = ctx.write(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192)), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
```

Comment: Thx alot, this is working. But yet I don't understand why it works. Why I need to add a HttpChunkedInput?

Comment: Because otherwise ChunkedWriteHandler will produce ByteBuf and not HttpContent. Spdy handlers expect HttpContent.